# updating page views in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, view

I'm creating my site located [here](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2).

on my singles page ([example](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2/single.php?id=Free%20Sim%20Card)) where it displays only one item, I want it to update the views field in my database called "mobi" with a +1 hit which is currently set as int(6).

I want it to hit for what ever the promo_title is being viewed from the database.

the page connects to the database via the `include_once` php code on all of my pages.

the code I have been using is this:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare ("UPDATE mobi SET views = views +1 WHERE promo_title= ? ");
$query->bindValue(1, $promo_title);
$query->execute();
```

But it does not seem to work.

please can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

**is there an alternative way of doing this?**

if you require any more info then please ask and I will update this.

thank you.

Comment: What doesn't work? What errors?

Comment: my code does not update my field on my database with a hit and no error messages are displaying. (I have error reporting tuned on) Other wise I would have said.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: what has that got to do about this Fred?

Comment: Try running print $query->errorCode(); after your execute statement to see if there is in fact a PDO error generated.

Comment: nope. no error message.

Comment: How does a row get into your table for each new value of `promo_title` so the UPDATE operation can work on it?

Comment: I add it when I upload the content.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `$query->rowCount();` if you invoke it immediately after the `execute()`?

I bet it's zero. I bet your `WHERE` clause is not matching any rows.

It's possible that the first time you attempt to update the table for a given `promo_title`, no matching row has yet been inserted.  If that's true you have to insert the row.

It's possible that your  `promo_title` column is a `CHAR(n)` column rather than a `VARCHAR(n)` column.   Try this SQL instead of what you have to test this hypothesis:

```
UPDATE mobi SET promo_views = promo_views +1 WHERE TRIM(promo_title) = TRIM(?)
```

Notice that the performance of this will be terrible, as the `TRIM` function on `promo_title` definitively defeats the use of any index.  But if it works, you'll have a clue about what's wrong.

Comment: got this error:- Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in single.php

Comment: also my promo_title is VARCHAR(255)

Comment: Which statement threw the the `Invalid parameter number` error?

Comment: it says line 13 and my line 13 is `$query->execute();`

Comment: MY MISTAKE the code was because I deleted the `$query->bindValue(1, $promo_title);` and adding that back in removes the warning but still does not update the database. would it help if I past my whole single.php page?

Comment: Please see the question in the first line of my answer.

Comment: using your code above but changing `$query->bindValue(1, $promo_title);` to `$query->bindValue(1, $id);` sorts out the issue, thank you for your help.